# JavaScript Object Literal - how to replace `this` keyword for another thing

Tags: javascript, methods, binding, this, object-literal

Is there any way to avoid the constant use of the `this` keyword to access the properties and methods of the current object?

I tried something like in `Example 2`, but it doesn't work at all.

**Example 1:**

```
<script>

  var fruits = {

    printApple(){ return "Apple"; },

    printBanana(){ return "Banana"; },

    printPear(){ return "Pear"; },

    printAll(){ return "All Fruits: " + this.printApple() + ", " + this.printBanana() + ", " + this.printPear(); }

  }

  alert(fruits.printAll());

</script>
```

**Example 2:**
*(this script doesn't work, don't use it)*

```
<script>

  var fruits = {

    y(){ return this.fruits; },

    printApple(){ return "Apple"; },

    printBanana(){ return "Banana"; },

    printPear(){ return "Pear"; },

    printAll(){ return "All Fruits: " + y.printApple() + ", " + y.printBanana() + ", " + y.printPear(); }

  }

  alert(fruits.printAll());

</script>
```

Comment: this is a question, for the `example 2` how can i avoid the constant use of the `this` keyword, and replace for something more shortable. Or simply do not use.

Comment: Javascript is a deliberately stripped-down object language, and already complex enough for beginners. All improvements in its syntax tend towards simplification; If you have a suggestion I would be curious to read it, but I warn you a lot has been tried and things like operator overloading are ruled out.

Comment: I guess I just don't understand why using `this` is bad?

Comment: Since `fruits` is static, why not use `fruits.printApple() ...`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems the most idiomatic way and easy way is to use function constructors (hard objects). Actually I prefer it over prototypes and it's very good for the mixin design pattern.

Regarding your question - no nice object literal alternative exists but you could use an anonymous constructor function:

```
const obj = new function(){
  // your constructor here
};
```

Also tested on thousands of object against prototypes and the difference in performance is negligible for the most cases.

One another benefit that you don't care about proper `this` binding anymore and can pass method refs safely, because the `this` binding happens in the constructor.

```js
function Fruits(){

  // add public methods here, use `self` anywhere as a safe alternative for `this`
  const self = Object.assign(this, { printAll, alertMe });

  function printApple() {
    return "Apple";
  }

  function printBanana() {
    return "Banana";
  }

  function printPear() {
    return "Pear";
  }

  function printAll() {
    return "All Fruits: " + printApple() + ", " + printBanana() + ", " + printPear();
  }
  
  function alertMe() {

    // use `self` if you allow to override the method in a mixin

    alert(self.printAll());

  }
}

function MixedFruits() {

  // call Fruits as a constructor on the current `this`

  Fruits.call(this);
  Object.assign(this, { printAll });

  function printAll(){
    return 'printAll() has been overridden!!!';
  }

}

const fruits = new Fruits;

console.log(fruits.printAll());

const mixedFruits = new MixedFruits;

// we don't care about `this` when passing methods as arguments
$base.addEventListener('click', fruits.alertMe);
$overridden.addEventListener('click', mixedFruits.alertMe);
```

```html
<button id="$base">Fruits::alertMe()</button>
<br/>
<br/>
<button id="$overridden">MixedFruits::alertMe()</button>
```

Comment: `const self = Object.assign(this, { printAll });` it's a nice alternative for my full project. TY for your precious help, and it's a real construtive answer/solution at my question.

Answer (score 2):

Since the OP's real dilemma/problem has been pictured by some of the OP's comments ...

> *".., because of this non beautiful and non readable code: [imgur.com/WJ7pzxP](https://imgur.com/WJ7pzxP)"* – Edgaras

... the only approach which can tackle it is locally accessing the methods from its `this` context and reassigning a [bound version](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to each of the local variables.

My above comment already points into this direction ...

> *"@Edgaras ... In this case the OP could write ...*
>
> *`let { elm, Element_Create, Element_Declare /* ... */ } = this;`*
>
> *... for every method of `this` and then rebind it like ...*
>
> *`elm = elm.bind(this); Element_Create = Element_Create.bind(this); /* ... */`*
>
> *... in order to just use/invoke the method names, but each within its correct context."*

Using the OP's provided, already simplified, code example the latter then should be rewritten to ...

```js
var fruits = {

  apple: 'Apple',
  pear: 'Pear',
  banana: 'Banana',

  getApple() { return this.apple; },
  getPear() { return this.pear; },
  getBanana() { return this.banana; },

  printAll() {
    // access and assign every needed method from the `this` context.
    let { getApple, getPear, getBanana } = this;

    // reassign each method by its own bound variant each rebinding `this`.
    [getApple, getPear, getBanana] = [getApple, getPear, getBanana]
      .map(getter => getter.bind(this));

    // invoke the rebound method names without the connecting dot operator.
    return `All Fruits: ${ getApple() }, ${ getPear() }, ${ getBanana() }`;
  },
};

console.log(
  fruits.printAll()
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: TY for your solution, and the constructive explanation for the JS community.

Answer (score 0):

The use of `this` like many languages is unavoidable. especially when you need to access properties or methods of the same object.

`this` keyword is special variable that every execution context gets and it automatically set by the JS engine.

Your example 2 - the script does not work because `y` is not defined in the global context.

```js
      var fruits = {
    
        printApple(){ return "Apple"; },
    
        printBanana(){ return "Banana"; },
    
        printPear(){ return "Pear"; },
    
        printAll(){
          var self = this;
          return "All Fruits: " + self.printApple() + ", " + self.printBanana() + ", " + self.printPear(); 
        }
      }
    
      alert(fruits.printAll());
```

Comment: but if i had multiple `printAll()` as `printAll_1()` , `printAll_2()`, etc...  i will need to declare this "var self = this;" in all of them? There's no other way?

Comment: @Edgaras the link I gave above, and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616202/self-references-in-object-literals-initializers should help. Also, what's wrong with using `this`?

Comment: @evolutionxbox, because of this non beautiful and non readable code: https://imgur.com/WJ7pzxP

Comment: @Edgaras ... In this case the OP could write `let { elm, Element_Create, Element_Declare /* ... */ } = this;` for every method of `this` and then rebind it like `elm = elm.bind(this); Element_Create = Element_Create.bind(this); /* ... */`, in order to just use/invoke the method names, but each within its correct context.